# Android - TextView Lags when having a fast counter

Tags: android, textview, counter, lag

I have recently gotten into Android coding and I thought that one of the first few apps I can make is a counter app. The user simply pushes a button on the bottom of the screen and a TextView counts up with each number appearing for 100 milliseconds. In addition, I also having a tick sound playing in the background each time the number changes. The problem is, however, is that sometimes the counter lags. Every once in a while it skips 1 or 2 numbers, but the clicking sound still goes. Here is the relevant code for the button press:

```
public void onRedButtonPress(View view) {
    count = 0;
    limit = 40;
    final TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Counter);

    final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    final float maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (count < limit) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);

                    float actualVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
                    soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);

                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

                }
                counter.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        counter.setText("" + count);
                    }
                });
                count++;
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Here is activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Counter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:text="0"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/selector"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onRedButtonPress" />

</LinearLayout>
```

"@drawable/selector" is simply an xml that switches between the two images of a pressed button and normal button.

I tried changing "new Thread(...)" to "runOnUiThread(...)" but then it only showed 0 and 40 and no numbers in between. I'm using AudioManager to get the sound setting on the device and SoundPool to actually play the sound. The sound is stored as a .wav file. Is there any way to make it not lag or do simply have to increase the duration of each number? I'm using Android Studio if that matters.

**EDIT:** I tried unplugging my device from the computer cause I thought my phone was sending LogCat information each time the number changed. It didn't lag the first time, but then subsequent times it started lagging again.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you're sleeping for 100 milliseconds in your thread. If the goal of that sleep is to execute your code on an interval of 100 seconds try using a Handler object instead. Read up on it. You can create one like this:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

This taps into the message queue of the main thread in the Android OS. If you wanted something to happen every 100 milliseconds you can do something like this:

```
  mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Do your work in here
                // Update the TextView

                // If you want to run this again in 100 ms?
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);

                // If not then by not reposting this Runnable won't get called anymore
                // In your case if you hit your limit, don't run this again
            }
  }
```

I don't think you need a Thread for firing a sound notification. Also keep in mind that creating a new Thread is a costly process. Is you absolutely need one, look into ThreadPoolExecutors in Java. This manages the thread creation and the executing of your Runnables for you.

One more thing you could do is to cache the references to your TextView, the AudioManager and the max volume instead of fetching references every time the button is pressed. Those variables don't change inside your code so just instantiate them once as members and reuse them.

Comment: Also, Threads live longer than the Activity lifecycle so it is really easy to leak if care is not taken. Specially if you are creating anonymous inner classes.

Comment: Good point. I personally wouldn't use a different thread unless you're doing something that blocks (waiting for a socket connection) or doing some massive computation that would take over the UI Thread for a significant amount of time. Handlers are even better than TimerTasks as those also tie up Threads to do their intervals. Handlers are pretty sweet.

Comment: Yeah, the same thing applies to Handlers, they can live past the Activity lifecycle since they are tied to the `MessageQueue`

Comment: You could just store a boolean in the Activity and use that as a condition to post the request to the Handler again. You might even be able to just do a check if ActivityClass.this is null then don't  repost. Not positive about that though. It really depends what you're intent is.